# SonarQube not working with .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

I'm not sure if the .net core version has anything to do, I'm also using visual studio 2017.

I'm trying to analyze a project using the sonarscanner for msbuild version 4.0.1, but I keep getting the message "The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects." eventhough I execute the following commands, in the same order:

1. SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin
2. MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
3. SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end

Does SonarQube not support .net core projects?

Comment: See this [SonarSource](https://blog.sonarsource.com/supporting-analysis-of-net-core-projects) article.

Comment: It should work, just make sure that you are using the latest Scanner for MSBuild (4.0.2+) and latest SonarC# (6.7.1+). If you still have trouble analyzing your projects, in order to help you I will need the complete log of the three commands executed with /d:sonar.verbose=true for scanner begin and /v:diag for msbuild.